# PHP, Insert data to SQL

Tags: php

I have a problem with my current admin panel. I need a little help.
When I upload an image (sphere_render) and put alttext for it,
It's working correctly and inserting data into the database.

When I add some gallery images and write them alt texts, sphere_render alttext isn't working.
But gallery images alttext working correctly.
Somehow alttext placeholder works for two different tables.

one table for sphere render alttext: column named alttext

another table for gallery images: column named gallery_image_alttext

Input page:

```php
<body>
<?php include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/admin/header.php'); ?>
<div id="page-wrapper">
<div id="page">

<form action="/admin/new_tex_submit.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="new-tex-form">

<?php
if(isset($_GET["error"])) {
    echo "<div class=\"form-item error\">";
    echo "<h2>Error: </h2>";
    echo "<p> ".$_GET["error"]."</p>";
    echo "</div>";
}
?>

<div class="form-item">
    <h2>Upload sphere render:</h2>

    <div class="u1">
        <input type="file" name="sphere_render" id="sphere-render" required>
        <div id="sphere-render-preview-wrapper" class="hidden">
        <img src="#" id="sphere-render-preview">

    </div>
    <input type="text" name="alttext"/>
</div>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){ // wait for page to load

    $('#withEvents').MultiFile({
        max: 20,
        onFileRemove: function(element, value, master_element) {
            $('#F9-Log').append('<li>onFileRemove - ' + value + '</li>')
        },
        afterFileRemove: function(element, value, master_element) {
            $('#F9-Log').append('<li>afterFileRemove - ' + value + '</li>')
        },
        onFileAppend: function(element, value, master_element) {
            $('#F9-Log').append('<li>onFileAppend - ' + value + '</li>')
        },
        afterFileAppend: function(element, value, master_element) {
            $('#F9-Log').append('<li>afterFileAppend - ' + value + '</li>')
        },
        onFileSelect: function(element, value, master_element) {
            $('#F9-Log').append('<li>onFileSelect - ' + value + '</li>')
        },
        afterFileSelect: function(element, value, master_element) {
            console.log(element, value, master_element);
            console.log('id:'+element.id);

            var a = '<div class="as"><input placeholder="caption" type="text" name="caption[]" id="'+element.id+'_caption'+'"></input><input name="alttext[]" placeholder="Alt text" type="text" id="'+element.id+'_alttext'+'"></input></div>';

            $('.MultiFile-preview:last').after(a);
            a='';
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

new_tex_submit.php only with mentioned with "alttext"

```php
<?php

$conn = db_conn_read_write();  // Create Database connection first so we can use `mysqli_real_escape_string`

$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["name"]);
$scale = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["scale"]);
$author = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["author"]);
$slug = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["slug"]);

$download = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["download"]);
$patreon_level = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["patreon_level"]);
$yoast_title = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["yoast_title"]);
$yoast_metadesc = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["yoast_metadesc"]);
$tex1_meta = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["tex1_meta"]);
$blogtext = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["blogtext"]);        
**$alttext = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["alttext"]);**

// Database stuff
$sql_fields = [];
$sql_fields['name'] = $name;
$sql_fields['scale'] = $scale;
$sql_fields['author'] = $author;

$sql_fields['download'] = $download;
$sql_fields['patreon_level'] = $patreon_level;

$sql_fields['yoast_title'] = $yoast_title;
$sql_fields['yoast_metadesc'] = $yoast_metadesc;
$sql_fields['tex1_meta'] = $tex1_meta;
$sql_fields['blogtext'] = $blogtext;
$sql_fields['alttext'] = $alttext;

/ Insert gallery !!

$captions = array_reverse($_POST['caption']);
**$alttexts = array_reverse($_POST['alttext']);**

$sig=0;

foreach ($_POST['caption'] as $gals) {

    $impath = 'wp-content/2020/'.$_FILES['galleryImage']['name'][$sig];

    $sql_gallery = "INSERT INTO gallery (post_id,photo_id,image_title,image_url,image_caption,**image_alt_text)** VALUES ($last_id,$sig,'','{$impath}','{$captions[$sig]}','{$alttexts[$sig]}')";
    // echo $sql_gallery;
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_gallery);

    $uploaddir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-content/2020/';
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir .$_FILES['galleryImage']['name'][$sig];

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['galleryImage']['tmp_name'][$sig], $uploadfile);
    $sig++;

}
```

// Insert gallery end !!

Comment: You should look into using parameterized [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of manually escaping and injecting the user data into the queries like that.

Comment: Thanks but I'm not good enough on php to change something like that. I need a solution with my alt-text input problem. Can you suggest me anything about it ?

Answer (score 0):

I just change the gallery images placeholder names with alttext1.
It's working correctly now.